# Invert scrolling on Windows Bootcamp

Tags: windows, bootcamp

It just irritates me a little bit that when I scroll in Windows, I have to scroll normally, but on Mac OS X, I have to change back to the other scrolling (Inverted), I prefer the Mac OS X way, is there a way to have this setting on Windows using Bootcamp settings or such?

Comment: See http://www.howtogeek.com/57542/how-to-get-the-worst-os-x-lion-feature-in-windows-reverse-scrolling/ or: http://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel

Answer (score 41):

From user3669959's linked answer:

1. Open the Mouse settings in the Control Panel
2. Click on the Hardware tab, "HID-compliant device", Properties
3. Click on the Details tab
4. Choose Device Instance Path in the Property drop down menu
5. Note the VID value
6. Run regedit
7. Edit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_???\VID_???\Device Parameters, where the ??? is the VID value we just found
8. Edit FlipFlopWheel
9. Change the value from 0 to 1
10. Close all programs
11. Reboot

This worked for me on a Windows 7 64 bit PC, using the Boot Camp 5.1.5769 AppleWirelessTrackpad64.exe driver.

References:

https://web.archive.org/web/20220924160017/https://www.tsentas.net/windows-bootcamp-reverse-scrolling/

Answer (score 20):

I've written a small c# app to change the registry settings for all devices. It enumerates every device and changes the 'FlipFlopWheel' setting to 1 or 0 depending on which button you press.

The full source is available on Github, the source code that actually does the flipping the registry setting (<100 lines) is here: https://github.com/jamie-pate/flipflop-windows-wheel/blob/master/Form1.cs

For those just wanting to 'get it done' here is the executable (asks for UAC elevation) https://github.com/jamie-pate/flipflop-windows-wheel/blob/master/bin/Debug/FlipWheel.exe

Comment: I just downloaded and ran the Flipwheel application and clicked on Invert All. But there seem to be no changes, can you explain a bit to newbies like me how to go about it. Also nothing like UAC elevation was asked

Comment: @Abhay I think this software changes the registry and you'd need to restart/re-login in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you! This worked on Windows 10 with 2016 Macbook Pro 15”

Comment: It didn't work on Windows 10 installed via Bootcamp 6.1 on MB 12".

Comment: Confirming it works after restarting on a MBP 16"

Answer (score 8):

[Windows BootCamp reverse scrolling](https://web.archive.org/web/20220924160017/https://www.tsentas.net/windows-bootcamp-reverse-scrolling/):

> There is a registry setting named FlipFlopWheel that does exactly this and can be found after typing regedit in Run and pressing enter which will launch Registry Editor. Then search for keyword FlipFlopWheel.
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_???\VID_???\Device Parameters.
> ```
>
> The search will find multiple mouse entries. The default value for FlipFlopWheel will be 0 and needs to change to 1. After the change reboot in order to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently switched from Parallels to Bootcamp for doing 3ds Max work. This issue drove me bananas! I finally found this fantastic utility, called Trackpad++. It not only solved the 'natural scrolling' issue, but also brought back things like three-finger drag, and other gestures. It really is the perfect solution (and no, I don't know the developer):
http://trackpad.forbootcamp.org/

Comment: I get "not found" for this site.

Comment: Updated link :)

Comment: it looks good but Trackpad++ has some bizarre weekly update requirement - just a red flag.

Comment: Tried changing the regex FlipFlopWheel and rebooting but still the same. Installed Trackpadd++ and while it offered me no authorised Windows certs, and Defender warned me against running it, once it was running it worked with default settings. Its on a 2nd Macbook air, not sure I would put it on my main macbook, but will keep an eye on it and see if there is any undesired behaviour

Answer (score 4):

And to invert *horizontal* scrolling, use a very similar Powershell script (remember to run Powershell as administrator):

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\*\*\Device` Parameters FlipFlopWheel -EA 0 | ForEach-Object { Set-ItemProperty $_.PSPath FlipFlopHScroll 1 }
```

(note `FlipFlopHScroll` instead of `FlipFlopWheel`)

(Per [this link](https://fluentbytes.com/tweaks-after-setting-up-a-mac-book-pro-with-boot-camp-as-a-windows-machine/#comment-195531))

Answer (score 1):

I use this free program to set the scroll wheel to reverse scroll in windows 10. I also use it in windows 7 at work and set the work mouse wheel button to back. Super useful.

https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 1):

**It worked for me this way:**

1. Open Control Panel.
2. In the search field at top right type, 'mouse' and hit enter.
3. Click on 'mouse' in green - the top one!.
4. the very last tab of the window that popped up will be your device's software settings - click it and open up the settings program.
5. Click on Two Finger Scrolling under Multi-Finger Gestures and select GEAR symbol.
6. Select (or deselect) "Enable reverse scrolling direction".

Comment: I couldn't find these settings - the 'very last tab' says Harwdware not software settings.

Comment: "the very last tab of the window that popped up will be your device's software settings", No, it isn't - the question asked how to reverse scrolling direction in bootcamp, and the bootcamp driver does not offer this.

Answer (score 0):

The latest bootcamp software will label the trackpad as “precision touchpad” which will give you the “scrolling direction” setting under windows settings. To get the latest bootcamp version, open “Apple Software Update” and update as many times as needed. I had to do it twice.